# order counter in WooCommerce returns status 500

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, counter

While creating a function that returns an int counting the WooCommerce orders status and the WooCommerce order notes, I couldn't make it work and I don't know exactly what I'm doing it wrong.

I know that wc_orders_count( $status ) returns the orders count of a specific order status, if I am using the wrong function, which must be used? and if I'm using it wrong, how must be used?

here is the function

```
 add_action( 'init' 'custom_counter' );
    function custom_counter() {
        $customer_orders = get_posts( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
            'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
            'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
            'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
            'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
        ) ) );
        if ( $customer_orders ) {
            $status = wc_get_order( $customer_orders )->get_status();
            $orderscounter = wc_orders_count( $status );
            ?>  
                <p class="counter">
                <?php echo $orderscounter; ?>
                </p>
            <?php
        }
```

**EDIT**

Actually, I'm looking for a function that returns an alert when a new order is placed or an order status is updated, so I don't know if a counter is what I need.

**EDIT 2**

I just want the function to work properly. Let says that a customer it has a new order and we (admins) update the status of this order from "on hold" to "completed" we need the customer knows about this status change in the front end of the page as an alert (but no matter what the alert is, that's the easy part of the job, you can forgot about that, I can do it), so... any order status change or note order from an admin must be returned, for that reason I don't need a counter.

Comment: you was tried to debug the code?

Comment: not actually just gives me a status 500 @GanganiRoshan

Comment: you can try debug the code and say after which line return this status code.

Comment: In the google developer console?... do you know about wordpress woocommerce?

Comment: replacet add_action( 'init', 'custom_counter' );

Comment: can't... that hook, makes me show the function on wordpress...please don't comment if you don't know about wordpress or woocommerce

Comment: Your Edit is not enough clear… How this alert needs to be done? What order status changes are you targeting? Anyway, "init" hook is not really the good way for that. You should reedit your question and better explain what do you really want to do and how.

Comment: I edit again the question @LoicTheAztec ... as you see below, I'm targeting all the orders statuses and order notes, not actually "targeting" but returning them, for the customer as a notification. 
I just need that function, I will see later how to show it (so.. forgot about the hook)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify this function data as per require i hope this is helpful.

```
function display_woocommerce_order_count( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        'status' => 'completed',
    ), $atts );
    $statuses    = array_map( 'trim', explode( ',', $args['status'] ) );
    $order_count = 0;
    foreach ( $statuses as $status ) {
        // if we didn't get a wc- prefix, add one
        if ( 0 !== strpos( $status, 'wc-' ) ) {
            $status = 'wc-' . $status;
        }
        $order_count += wp_count_posts( 'shop_order' )->$status;
    }
    ob_start();
    echo number_format( $order_count );
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode( 'wc_order_count', 'display_woocommerce_order_count' );
```

After Edit Question Try below Answer:

As Xcid's answer indicates, you need to register the email.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed', array( WC(), 'send_transactional_email' ), 10, 10 );
```

I'd added a filter to WooCommerce 2.3, so when that comes out custom emails will be able to be added to the list of email actions that WooCommerce registers:

```
// As of WooCommerce 2.3
function so_27112461_woocommerce_email_actions( $actions ){
    $actions[] = 'woocommerce_order_status_wc-order-confirmed';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_actions', 'so_27112461_woocommerce_email_actions' );
```

Comment: For some reason this shortcode display a wrong number. Actually, I'm looking for a function that returns an alert when a new order is placed or an order status is updated, so I don't know if a counter is what I need

Comment: for is not working properly, if I have 6 orders on the shop, it returns 3

Comment: As you see above in my edited question, now I don't need a counter, I need an alert for a customer to know when their orders or note orders are updated